# Use MySQL from AMPPS with Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ampps

I'm trying to use Rails with the MySQL bin from Ampps, but when I run the command `rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string` I get the following error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_server_init
Referenced from: /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_server_init
  Referenced from: /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

I have already configured Ampps Mysql with my environment but I can not managed to make it work with rails, I have the following configurations.

```
$ which mysql                                          
/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin/mysql

$ echo $PATH
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/myusername/.rvm/bin:/Users/myusername/.rvm/bin:/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin

$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/libmy*.dylib 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myusername  admin  53 Jan  1 19:30 /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib -> /Applications/AMPPS/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

I have tried doing commands but with no success:

```
$ gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-lib=/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/lib --with-mysql-include=/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/include --with-mysql-config=/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

And

```
bundle config build.mysql2 --with-mysql-lib=/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/lib --with-mysql-include=/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/include --with-mysql-config=/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin/mysql_config
bundle install
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `file /Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin/mysql` tell you? Symbol not found errors are often a result of architecture mismatches.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to mark my answer as accepted? Did it not solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I assigned the points and thought that was enough to mark it as accept it my bad :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded this AMPPS package and did a quick check on the MySQL binary:

```
$ file /Volumes/AMPPS/AMPPS/mysql/bin/mysql
/Volumes/AMPPS/AMPPS/mysql/bin/mysql: Mach-O executable i386
```

Your 64-bit Ruby install is trying to link to 32-bit MySQL libraries, and is not finding what it's looking for. "Symbol not found" errors are often an indication of an architecture mismatch.

My advice to you would be to install these programs from a package management system such as MacPorts or Homebrew. I'm partial to MacPorts, so I'll give you instructions for that. I get the impression Homebrew is more popular, but haven't used it myself.

1. Install Xcode and the Xcode Command Line Tools
2. Agree to Xcode license in Terminal: `sudo xcodebuild -license`
3. Install MacPorts: https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.3.4-10.11-ElCapitan.pkg
4. Update the port list: `sudo port selfupdate`
5. Install away: `sudo port install mysql56 rb-rails rb-mysql`
6. Update regularly: `sudo port selfupdate && sudo port -uc upgrade outdated`

This way you're getting properly built binaries for your system, you can easily keep them up to date, and you aren't filling your system up with 2 gigabytes of things you aren't necessarily going to use (5 different versions of PHP, a couple of database servers, Perl, Python, etc.) In addition, you also get up-to-date versions of other utilities like Ruby, rather than relying on the outdated version that ships with the operating system.